# Clicking on an element sets focus but not cursor?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, focus, cursor

I have an html page where I set the focus on the first input element on load. I can see that the focus is set because I ask the background of the element to go orange and I can see the orange background. However, the cursor is not shown in the element.

Then when I click on the other input elements, I can see the focus move to them but still no cursor is shown. The cursor only appears when I use the tab key.

Please could someone explain to me why this happens and how I can make this cursor appear without having to use the tab key?

This is for IE8 only. (It's an intranet site)

Code as requested for how I'm setting focus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rachel').focus();
});
```

**EDIT**

I didn't think to mention that the problem is happening on a popup window that looks to be implemented like a layer. Is it possible for layers to block the cursor?

Comment: What is the code that you are using to set focus?

Comment: what code you use to set focus?

Comment: Sounds like a strange CSS thing... Or an IE bug. What CSS and which version IE are you using?

Comment: It's IE8 and I don't know the CSS version but I do know that it's not valid CSS (and I know that's a problem...). Even if someone could explain to me how the focus and the cursor are related that would be great.

Comment: Not sure on the real answer, but I've found behavior sporadic across browsers.  Also, it seems calling .focus() is slightly different than actually clicking on an element which makes no sense to me.  One thing to look for is a focus event handler on $('#rachel') that returns false or cancels propagation.  Also try clicking on the input element manually and see if the blinking cursor appears.